# How to delete everything before a key phrase in text files?

Tags: python

I have over 5000 textfiles (also in csv format) with quite a few hundred lines in each.

Everything above a particular phrase, "City" is unnecessary and I need everything beneath it, is there a way (python or batch) to delete everything?

Answer (score 5):

I *love* python.  But sometimes, [`sed`](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) can be useful too:

```
sed -n '/City/,$p' file_with_city > new_file_with_city_on_first_line
```

Comment: +1 - if sed is available, this will be quicker than Python.

Comment: @Blair -- My philosophy: If it's not POSIX, it's not an OS  ;-)

Comment: Agree with you 100%, but there are some heretics out there...

Comment: you can generalize it to [edit multiple files inplace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14266747/4279)

Answer (score 2):

One algorithm is this:

- Read from the file until you encounter the text "City"
- Open a second file in write mode
- Stream from the first file into the second
- Close both files
- Move the second file into the location previously occupied by the first

Although files can be truncated to remove contents *after* a certain point, they cannot be resized-in-place with contents *before* a certain point. You could do this using a single file by repeatedly seeking back and forth, but it's probably not worthwhile.

If the files are small enough, you can just read the whole of the first file into memory and then write the portion of it you want back to the same on-disk file.

Answer (score 2):

`sed -i -n '/City/,$p' file1 file2 etc` analog in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

copy = False
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True): # edit files inplace
    if fileinput.isfirstline() or not copy: # reset `copy` flag for next file
       copy = "City" in line
    if copy:
       print line, # copy line
```

Usage:

```
$ ./remove-before-city.py file1 file2 etc
```

This solution modifies files given at the command-line inplace.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Use a context manager to make sure the files are properly closed.
with open('in.csv', 'r') as infile, open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    # Read the file line by line...
    for line in infile:
        # until we have a match.
        if "City" in line:
            # Write the line containing "City" to the output.
            # Comment this line out if you don't want to include it.
            outfile.write(line)

            # Read the rest of the input in one go and write it
            # to the output. If you file is really big you might
            # run out of memory doing this and have to break it
            # into chunks.
            outfile.write(infile.read())

            # Our work here is done, quit the loop.
            break
```

Comment: you shouldn't mix iterating over file using `for line in infile` that has its own read-ahead buffer and `infile.read()` operation. You could use `for line in iter(infile.readline, '')` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def removeContent(file, word, n=1, removeword=False):
    with open(fname, "r") as file:
        if removeword:
            content = ''.join(file.read().split(word, n)[n])
        else:
            content = word + ''.join(file.read().split(word, n)[n])
    with open(fname, "w") as file:
        file.write(content)

for fname in filenames:
    removeContent(fname)
```

Parameter explanations:

`n` tells us which occurrence of the word do you want it to use for removing. By default `n = 1` so it removes everything before the FIRST occurrence. To remove evertything before fifth `city`, call the function with `removeContent(fname, "city", 5)`.

`file` obviously represents the name of the file you want to edit

`word` is the word you want to use for removing, in your case it would be `city`

`removeword` tells wether to keep the word and only remove text before it, or if to remove the word itself too.

Comment: Careful: this will also *remove* occurrences of the word "city".

Comment: Took care of it, thanks for the notice :P

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't.  Look at `"a\ncity,b\ncity,c\n".split("city")` to see the problem.  There are a few ways to get around this (changing what you're `join`ing on, using `maxsplit`, etc.)

Comment: Sorry to be "that guy", but you can only use the `maxsplit` trick if `n==1`.  If `n = 2`, for example, then you'll remove two `city` instances and only add one back.

Comment: Why would I have to add two back? If I set `n=2`, it means I want to remove everything before the second occurrence... Including the first occurrence, which no longer needs to be added back.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("."):
    infile = open(file, 'rb')
    line = infile.readline()
    # Sequential read is easy on memory if the file is huge.
    while line != '' and not 'City' in line:
        line = infile.readline()     # skip all lines till 'City' line
    # Process the rest of the file after 'City'
    if 'City' in line:
        print line     # prints to stdout (or redirect to outfile)
    while line != '' :
        line = infile.readline()
        print line
```